# issue while running uiautomator 2.0 tests on AWS device farm

Tags: amazon-web-services, android-uiautomator, aws-device-farm

I am new to automated testing, and started using uiautomator 2.0 with android studio, I have 3 apk files, app-debug, app-debug-androidTest-unaligned and app-debug-unaligned.

In AWS device farm first i am uploading the app-debug, then choose instrumentation type, then uploading the app-debug-andriodTest-unaligned.

And when tried to run only 2 tests (setup suite and tear down suite) are running. please help me identify the issue.

Comment: Please provide the Run URL.

Comment: here is the run url : https://us-west-2.console.aws.amazon.com/devicefarm/home?region=us-west-2#/projects/814481e5-3dde-44ac-b893-55c94882f089/runs/583b648c-2635-428a-ae36-0c3e63093c16

Comment: Hi Rohan,  Were you able to check the issue?